# フォルダの中の画像ファイルを認識する

Tags: python

画像が入っているフォルダ(before_images)から画像を1枚づつ読み込み，顔認識済みの画像を処理用のフォルダに入れたいのですが，
自分の書いたコードでは1枚の顔認識済みの画像しか処理用のフォルダ(after_images)にしか入っていませんでした．

自分が作成したコードのどこに間違いがあるのか見つけることができなかったので教えてください．

下記の2つのサイトを参考にコードを作成しました．
http://qiita.com/Algebra_nobu/items/bcaeeb9c45e87b9d547a
http://qiita.com/wwacky/items/98d8be2844fa1b778323

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import glob

# これは、BGRの順になっている気がする
color = (255, 0, 0) #青

# サンプル顔認識特徴量ファイル
cascade_path ="C:\Ana2\8.kikaigakusyuu\haarlow.xml"


# プログラムが存在するディレクトリの代入
current_dir = os.getcwd()
# 画像が存在するディレクトリの代入
before_images = glob.glob(current_dir + "\\before_images\\*") 

i = 0

for image in before_images:

    if image == current_dir + "\\before_images\\Thumbs.db":
        continue
    else:
        # 画像の読み込み
        image = cv2.imread(image)

       # グレースケール変換
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

       # 分類器
        cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_path)

       # 認識実行
        facerect = cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=1, minSize=(1, 1))

        if len(facerect) > 0:
    # 検出した顔を囲む矩形の作成
         for rect in facerect:
          cv2.rectangle(image, tuple(rect[0:2]),tuple(rect[0:2]+rect[2:4]), color, thickness=2)



    # 画像保存   
        cv2.imwrite(current_dir + '\\after_images\\' + str(i) + '.jpg', image) 

        i += 1
```

Comment: `for image in before_images:` 以降のコードのインデントがおかしい様に見受けられますが、転記ミスでしょうか？

Comment: 全体的にインデントがずれてるみたいですね。

Comment: @metropolis さん　ご指摘ありがとうございます。 構文のインデントがずれてました。修正してコンパイルは通ったのですが，やはり複数の認識済みの画像が処理用のフォルダの中に入ってなかったです。

Comment: まだインデントがずれてる箇所があります(認識実行と画像保存の直後)。あとこういうのはデバッガかprintデバッグで実際に処理が意図した通りに呼ばれてるかどうかを確認しましょう。例えば`for image in before_images:`の直後に`print(image)‘という行を追加すればfor文が複数回っているか確認できます。`# 画像保存`の直前に`print(i)`を入れれば保存するファイル名が変わっているか確認できます。

Comment: @tag1216 さん ご指摘いただきありがとうございました．　指摘頂いた通りインデントの位置がおかしかったです．　修正します．